# Bottom navigation bar hides on trying scroll

Tags: android, scroll, android-bottomnav

I have Activity with bottom navigation bar (via [roughike BottomBar library](https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar)). It's look like this:
[image]

When i'm trying to scroll page, bottom bar hides automatically. So, I get this:
[image]

I want avoid this effect. I do not want hide bottom bar when I'm just trying to scroll content but all content lies on screen.

But if page contains content more than one screen then bottom bar must hides on scroll (and now it's works fine).

My code doesn't have any listeners for scroll and my xml file looks like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".presentation.ui.mainactivity.MainActivity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/mainCord" >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/sliderContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/primary"
            android:theme="@style/ToolbarStyle"
            app:titleTextAppearance="@style/ToolbarStyle" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <com.roughike.bottombar.BottomBar
        android:id="@+id/bottomBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:bb_tabXmlResource="@xml/bottom_bar_tabs"
        app:bb_activeTabColor="@color/white"
        app:bb_inActiveTabColor="@color/bottom_bar_inactive_tab"
        app:bb_inActiveTabAlpha="1"
        app:bb_behavior="shy|shifting" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I'm looked for solution for my problem but found nothing. What can i do for avoid this effect?

**UPDATED:**

FAB is inside ViewPager. Layout for tab on screenshot look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/eventCoordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/refresh"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/eventsRecyclerView"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity = "center"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/emptyText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/secondary_text"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/empty_events_text"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_no_calendar"
            android:drawablePadding="4dp"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/createEventText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/create_event_text"
            android:textColor="@color/secondary_text"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/createEventButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/primary"
            android:text="@string/create_event"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/createEvent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp"
        style="@style/floating_action_button"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/eventsRecyclerView"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:elevation="6dp"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/loadingPanel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:indeterminate="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Hey I can not see you fab code. Is it inside your viewpager fragment?

Comment: @Tasneem you are right. I added layout of my fragment to question.

Answer (score 2):

app:bb_behavior="underNavbar"

You have an issue in the following code

```
<com.roughike.bottombar.BottomBar
    android:id="@+id/bottomBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    app:bb_tabXmlResource="@xml/bottom_bar_tabs"
    app:bb_activeTabColor="@color/white"
    app:bb_inActiveTabColor="@color/bottom_bar_inactive_tab"
    app:bb_inActiveTabAlpha="1"
    app:bb_behavior="shy|shifting" />
```

replace the

```
app:bb_behavior="shy|shifting"
```

with

```
app:bb_behavior="underNavbar"
```

Hope this works for you!

Comment: In this case bottom bar hides never. But I want to hide bottom bar when content scrolling. And do not hide when I'm just trying to scroll but all content lies on screen.

Comment: Please elaborate your scenario properly... It's not clear

Answer (score 0):

Check your manifest FILE and make sure you're not using full screen theme...However, you can use the following code to hide and show the bar on android higher than API 19. To hide the bar, just change `VISIBLE` to `GONE`, and make sure you call the `showNavBar()` method in both your `onCreate()` and `onResume()` method

```
public void showNavBar() {
        View view = getWindow().getDecorView();
        view.setSystemUiVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I fixed it by doing this:

In **activity_main.xml** add this to the **CoordinatorLayout**:

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

The **viewpager** should be like this:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

And in all your **Fragments**, they should start with **NestedScrollView** and must contain (fillViewport):

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    tools:context="com.khan.junaid.phonefans.MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/fans_list_view"
        />

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

These settings will make the fragments scrollable, and the content will no more be hiding behind the Navigation bar buttons.